# Keycloak - Users in Role missing after sync with LDAP

Tags: keycloak

I configured LDAP as User Federation (with role-ldap-mapper) and successfully imported users with their roles to Keycloak.
When I go to Users->{user}->Role Mappings I see every roles that are signed to a user (imported from LDAP), but when I go to Roles->{role}->Users In Role I see nothing.

Is it a bug or a feature? Or maybe I configure something wrong?

[Users roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTlzA.png)

[Empty Users in Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cJ4a.png)

[LDPA Role mapper configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWJ0h.png)

Comment: As there is no accepted answer: did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue with keycloak 12: a user has 2 roles, in 1 role I can see the user in the other the user list is empty

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: It seems that if I change the User Roles Retrieve Strategy FROM "GET_ROLES_FROM_USER_MEMBEROF_ATTRIBUTE" to "LOAD_ROLES_BY_MEMBER_ATTRIBUTE" it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I changed the Mode (inside LDAP role mapper) to Import instead of READ_ONLY and I was able to see users under a role.

Answer (score -1):

Please create mapper of type msad-lds-user-account-control-mapper.

It works for me.